# ¿Cómo añado un campo autoincremental a una tabla ya existente?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, autoincremento

En un proyecto con Django 2.2.2 y base de datos postgreSQL tengo un modelo que ahora mismo es del tipo:

```
class CosasMias(models.Model):
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'surname'),)
```

La tabla ha funcionado bien hasta la fecha y tiene bastantes datos. Por circunstancias, ya no quiero que `nombre` sea clave primaria para así permitir crear nuevas *cosasmias* sin el campo "referencia" de inicio. Por tanto, necesito quitar `primary_key=True` de "referencia" y dejarlo en:

```
referencia = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Para hacer esto necesito definir una nueva clave primaria. Esto lo puedo hacer de forma implícita o explícita: creando un [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) o simplemente dejando que Django lo administre.

En cualquiera de los casos, cuando creo la migración me sale el mensaje:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations api
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to cosasmias without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Si elijo "1" y le doy un valor y luego ejecuto `python manage migrate api`, ese valor me vale para el primer registro... pero en el segundo ya da el error de integridad:

> ```
> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "cosasmias_id" of table "api_cosasmias"
> ```

¿Cuál es la manera de crear un campo autoincremental en estas condiciones, teniendo en cuenta que ya hay [bastantes] datos en la tabla?

Comment: hola, veo que ya viste una pregunta similar en SO en inglés, pero quizás la olvidaste (es de hace varios meses), https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356512/11649862 te sirve?

Comment: @DannyTalent sí, recuerdo esa pregunta y he probado la solución, pero en este caso no funciona porque: 1) ya hay datos y 2) la tabla está relacionada con otra. He probado con lo indicado en https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517306/1983854 pero hay aspectos que no me han funcionado

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41185561/1983854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno esta ha sido una tarea que ni las doce pruebas de Astérix... por lo que empecemos por la enseñanza básica:

**Piensa bien qué clave primaria usas. Si dudas, no la definas y así será un identificador y todo resultará más fácil.**

---

Pasos para resolverlo:

#### Copia los datos actuales

- Crea un modelo idéntico al que quieres modificar, con la modificación ya hecha. Si tenías `Modelo`, llámalo `TmpModelo` o similar.
- Copia el contenido allí. Es decir, copia el contenido de `Modelo` en `TmpModelo`.
- Desvincula el modelo de los otros modelos que puedan estar relacionados. En mi caso lo hice creando un campo nuevo que guardaba el identificador *a palo seco*. Es decir, si `ModeloRelacionado` tiene `campo_modelo` como ForeignKey de `Modelo`, pues define `campo_modelo_fijo = models.IntegerField(default=1)` y en un archivo de migraciones vuelca el contenido de `campo_modelo` en `campo_modelo_fijo`.

#### Recupera los datos copiados

- Elimina el campo que querías modificar y renombra el temporal con el nombre original. Es decir, elimina `Modelo` y renombra `TmpModelo` a `Modelo`.
- Itera sobre los modelos relacionados y puebla los datos tirando de las referencias que has ido guardando durante el proces.
- Elimina los campos accesorios para guardar las referencias, del tipo `capo_modelo_fijo`.

Teniendo en cuenta que hay veces que no permite hacer más de una acción por migración, a mí finalmente me han salido ocho ficheros de migración.

Durante el proceso es posible que te salga algún error en el fichero de `admin.py` que gestiona las vistas en Django admin. Yo lo que hice fue comentar todas las tablas relacionadas al principio del proceso y descomentarlas al terminar el proceso.

Referencia que me ayudó bastante: [How to migrate from custom primary key to default id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198249/1983854).

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear ese Autofield sin definirlo como PK. Luego lo poblas con una funcion por consola insertandole un consecutivo. Cuando todos los registros tengan valor asignado. Entonces le quitas el primarykey a "referencia" y se lo pones a id(Autofield)